# Can't ping on same subnet

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, local-area-network

I have one server and about ten other computers connected to same LAN and IP configured to same subnet. No DHCP. All computers have static IPs. Server is 192.168.13.1. (Others are 13.x) It's running Windows Server 2008 R2. Sometimes suddenly one computer can't connect to it. So, I did a ping and it's giving a time-out error. I tried with another computer and it can successfully ping the server. Also, first computer can ping to all other computers. This happens randomly on all computers. Please help.

Comment: Maybe something with [NLA](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753545(v=ws.10).aspx)?

Comment: Answering this question is not really possible without doing some troubleshooting... Was this setup ever working before or it's a new network ? do you have duplicate IPs on the network ? have you checked the hardware level - is your switch working properly ? do you have teaming on the Windows server ? have you checked that the proper NIC driver is installed on your Windows 2008 R2 ? is it possible to try using another NIC in the Windows 2008 machine (it can also be a network card issue) ?

Comment: This setup worked almost a year now. We have not changed anything in the software side. I have changed NIC with PCI card. Issue still persist. I have changed the switch too.

Comment: Is this happening between the PCs too , or only the connection to the server is faulty ?

Comment: If it' only the connection to the server, I'd try to boot the server (if possible) with another OS, like a Fedora 22 live cd and see if network works.

Comment: does the issue self-cure itself, or how do you fix it? is the workstation coming out of sleep? One possibility is that your NIC might go into sleep after a period of idle time.

Comment: The thing is, when one computer can't connect, another one can. So, it's happening randomly. No pc to pc issue found yet.

Comment: I have found some useful information. Our server has zwcad license sever. Today I found one computer can't get zwcad license. So, I did ping to server. timeout occurred. So, I changed IP address of the computer and now it successfully ping. Then I opened zwcad software. Still can't get license and also as I open zwcad, timeout started happening. So, I changed IPs several times with same result. I have restarted zwcad license service and now it's working. But those IP's can't ping. What would be the cause?

Comment: Make sure the network card isn't going to sleep.  Go to the Local Area Connection properties.  Click configure.  Should have a tab that says Power Management.  Uncheck all of boxes.

Comment: Card is not going to sleep. Because it can ping other devices.